Where to post question about key signing for publishing on google play store
I am having trouble with publishing an app on the google play store.
I posted a question on Stack Overflow, but it was closed as off topic.
I tried publishing it on Android Stack Exchange site, but I didn't find any tag related to development.
Where can I post this question?

Stack Overflow is the closest you have, but it's a gray area: Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?

Looks like a Q&A has managed to survive there already
